# "perished of fits"

Tags: meaning, idioms, ambiguity

I can not find the meaning of this phrase: ***perished of fits***.

[image]

What does it mean? It is an idiom?

Comment: http://www.brainpickings.org/2011/01/19/edward-gorey-the-gashlycrumb-tinies/ scroll down to S (for Susan)

Comment: @Frank
I know Edward Gorey. He is the person who I owe this question. I want to know how I die.

Comment: It's really just a matter of what rhymes; there is no idiom (that I'm aware of) in _perished of fits_. As Martin says it's just one way to die (although probably a relatively unlikely one these days) - see SUDEP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudden_unexpected_death_in_epilepsy

Comment: @Frank - I hitched a ride on Susan's link ... great destination, Frank. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the context it is difficult to reply, but it seems as if someone/thing died as a result of a seizure, e.g., an epileptic fit

Answer (score 3):

Not only is it not an idiom, it is archaic both in the words and the expression.

*Perish* is a literary word for *die*; but though we use *die of* (a cause), *perish of* is rare: the British National Corpus has 204 instances of *perished*, but only two of *perished of*.

The OED says of *fit*: " A sudden seizure of any malady attended with loss of consciousness and power of motion, or with convulsions, as fainting, hysteria, apoplexy, paralysis, or epilepsy. In 18th c. often used spec. without defining word = ‘fainting-fit’ or ‘fit of the mother’ (i.e. of hysteria: see mother n.1); in recent use it suggests primarily the notion of an epileptic or convulsive fit."
So in earlier times, *fit* was rather a vague word, and *to die of fits* was a phrase that you might encounter without any clear idea of the exact cause of death.

I believe that Gorey deliberately uses such archaic expressions, to create the Gothic mood of much of his humour.

Comment: Perish the thought!

Comment: It also rhymes with the following "demise" `T is for Titus who flew into bits`